# Google Map API - Billing Enabled but did not receive client ID and crypto key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I enabled billing for Google MAP API but did not receive their welcome email that should contain the client ID and crypto key. Does anyone know how I can find these information? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is its on your developer console since that's where you enabled billing for that project. You'll still use the same client ID and crypto keys (if given), its just that google will charge you for the excess usage you've used.

You can also [contact their sales support](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/) for a more official answer.